# How can this answer have more than 500 reputation points as bounty?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

I just searched something, and stopped on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544380/improve-geshi-syntax-highlighting-for-t-sql). Here the one accepted answer has 2000 reputation points as bounty.

While in [help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), it clearly mentions that bounty range between 50 and 500.

> To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of
>   an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500
>   reputation, in 50-point increments.

Even the bounty drop-down show range from 50-500, then how is it possible? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe it was awarded multiple bounties.

Comment: It's received 4 bounties - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23773356/revisions

Comment: How can 1 answer again n again received bounty? This is not weird?

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName hey as long as the other users are willing to "pay" for the bounty, there's no reason not to award them.

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Several were started to reward and existing answer - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23544380/revisions

Comment: My bad, why I not just go to revision and check this...

Comment: I find it comical that the tooltip when hovering over the bounty displays `This answer has been awarded bounties worth 2050 reputation by Aaron Bertrand, Aaron Bertrand, ypercubeᵀᴹ, Aaron Bertrand and Petah`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It got multiple bounties:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/530630/jonathan-amend?tab=bounties&sort=earned

The answer received 4 times a 500 point bounty for this answer, for a total of 2000 points.
3 of these were given by the same user, [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand), who is over 100.000 points even after these bounties.

We can see it in the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23773356/revisions

Aaron Bertrand was the asker of the original question, I suppose he was really happy with the answer.