# Multiple bounties on a single question: is there a limit?

Tags: support

I'm expecting to put a bounty on one of my questions, and I was considering putting setting the bounty at 500 reputation. How would this affect things if I had to put up a second bounty on it? Would it have to be 1000 reputation (since each extra bounty has to be doubled)? Would it just have to be 500 again? Or would I be prevented from putting up the second bounty altogether?

Comment: The limit is [three active bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty ... ", if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on"

Comment: As far as I know, it caps at 500, and allows you to repeat that indefinitely. I've never tried.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's possible: it has happened. I discovered that when answering [this Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299717/how-can-this-answer-have-more-than-500-reputation-point-as-bounty).

Comment: This question has 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set any bounty, but

- At most 3 at a time (as pointed out by  Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå in the comments under your question).
- Only one active per question.

You can find this in the [Help Center entry about bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

If the previous bounty was less than 500, you must double the amount, to a maximum of 500.

After a 500-point bounty expires, you can add a 500-point bounty again.

There is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530630/jonathan-amend?tab=bounties&sort=earned) who received no less than 4 bounties of 500 points on the same question, 3 from the same user. That generous user was the person who asked the original question, so he set these bounties on his own question.